# What does "go to dust inside" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, vocabulary

I recently came across the phrase **"go to dust inside"**. What does it mean (in this paragraph)?

> The feelings that come with the realization are overwhelming. One part guilt, one part fear, they make us ill in soul. We know what we cannot admit. If we do not stay as we are, we will feel forever unfaithful. If we force ourselves to stay as we are, we will **go to dust inside**.

Could someone please help me understand the meaning of it?

Answer (score 1):

The source of the quote:
[Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=5y7Bg3V4BnkC&pg=PA120&lpg=PA120&dq=%22The%20feelings%20that%20come%20with%20the%20realization%20are%20overwhelming.%20One%20part%20guilt,%20one%20part%20fear%22&source=bl&ots=8vEyO1vv3d&sig=ACfU3U02p2vx-nwEhwpjRs1Sj4MhD5JxYg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjU9IC7o9vtAhXZKM0KHebGDMkQ6AEwAnoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22The%20feelings%20that%20come%20with%20the%20realization%20are%20overwhelming.%20One%20part%20guilt%2C%20one%20part%20fear%22&f=false)

> Following the Path: The Search for a Life of Passion, Purpose, and Joy
> By Joan Chittister

It means that once you discover that what you have held to has lost its meaning, you have the choice to change, or to continue holding to it. If you hold to what has become ashes, you become that.

To "go to dust" means 'to become dust".

Compare to "go to pieces", "go to pot".

Comment: can be mean "turn to dust"?

Comment: Yes, that means the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

To go to dust means to change into dust. It is a metaphor meaning that our inside will dry up and disintegrate like dust, to the point where there's nothing more alive there. Its substance will have no weight and will be able to be blown away with no effort.

Comment: aha, so it means "turn to dust"?

Comment: Yes, but in a figurative way, not a literal way. It doesn't mean it will be physically turned to dust.